# Deleted deleted temp appPools folder

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, iis

I accidentally deleted the deleted temp app Pools folder, what can I do all my sites dont show up? This is on server Windows 2008.  I restarted IIS but nothing.  I dont have access to a backup at the moment.

```
C:\inetpub\temp\appPools
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I restarted server and it looks like it recreated the folders.  Holy mother, why would Microsoft put important files like that in a folder named temp.  User error too, I should of been more careful and researched that!

Comment: Why would you run a system without backups?

Comment: It does have backups, just would of taken time to get it from the admins.

Answer (score 2):

The temporary configuration files in that folder are generated for security (isolation) reasons by the WAS process. There is a separate config file for each individual app pool. Details are described here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd163536.aspx

It seems that restarting an app pool or IIS is not sufficient to trigger the WAS process to regenerate the files. Only restarting the server appears to trigger the process to regenerate the files..

Although I didn't try it, is seems to me that restarting the WAS service should also be sufficient to trigger the regeneration of the files, as would be touching / changing the applicationHost.config file.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me and saved me from having to restart the server.

Answer (score 1):

You should restore the folder from Backup

Comment: What if I cant?

Comment: Then you might want to state that in your original question

Answer (score 1):

I agree with MichelZ that you should restore from backup, however that's assuming you took any manual backups before tweaking anything in IIS.  I would be backing up the server from a system level with some sort of backup software; obviously you can take your pick here from dozens of great vendors.  I would also be taking manual IIS backups before major changes.  IIS will take backups of its own, but it's nice to be able to go back to exactly where you want to.  To do this open a Command Prompt as Administrator and navigate to C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv

From here use the appcmd command like this:  C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\appcmd add backup "My Backup Name" (where My Backup Name is the name you give your backup)

Typically I like to name my backups something meaningful in case I have to go back and restore.  Something like *"Pre ASP Authentication Config on Site X"* that way I know that that is where I made big changes to ASP on a particular site in case I need to revert to before I made those changes.

[Good backup, restore source here.](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/03/24/how-to-backup-restore-iis7-configuration.aspx)